# Display Selected Date from Calendar on Unity in Input-field c#

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, c#-2.0

[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3g7S.png)

I created a calendar on Unity from scratch and have been trying to show the selected date in the input field (i.e when a user selects a specific date from the calendar it is shown with its respective month and year in the field). Atm it only shows the 1st day, and the month and year changes as a flick through the calendar. The calendar results are stored in "weeks" (for the days) and under "month&year". I want to make the input field to equal these variables, but nothing i've tried has worked so far. How can I get this to work? (any tips & resources would be great!)

```
private List<Day> days = new List<Day>();
public Transform[] weeks;
public Text MonthAndYear;
public DateTime currDate = DateTime.Now;
public InputField Date;


private void Start()
{
    UpdateCalendar(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
}

void UpdateCalendar(int year, int month)
{
    DateTime temp = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    currDate = temp;
    MonthAndYear.text = temp.ToString("MMMM") + " " + temp.Year.ToString();
    int startDay = GetMonthStartDay(year, month);
    int endDay = GetTotalNumberOfDays(year, month);
    Date.text = currDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: How are you detecting which date has been selected?

Comment: @HumanWrites that's the thing, it isn't detecting what's selected; I'm having issues with the whole process. I've been looking for anything that could help me with this!

Comment: Add a screen shot of your scene hierarchy with all your nested UI elements displayed and I'll add an answer explaining some possible approaches.  If the screenshot also showed your calendar, that would help.

Comment: Hi @HumanWrites , I added a sc of my scene - it's on top of the description, linked "Scene". Also thank you for your time and responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a script to the each Image in the Days prefab that allows you to set the day number and also detects interactions.  I'm not typing this in Unity/VS so it may have some minor errors but it will be something like:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DayScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {

    public int dayNumber;
    public GameObject dayText; // This is the Text component of the Image
    public Calendar cal; // This would be your Content Panel, which has the Calendar script attached.

    void Start() {
        dayText.GetComponent<Text>().text = dayNumber;
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData evtData) {
        cal.SetSelectedDay(dayNumber);
    }

}
```

Then in your Calendar script add the following class member and method changes:

```
private int SelectedDay;

// Change your Start method slightly
void Start()
{
    SelectedDay = 1;
    UpdateCalendar(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
}


public void SetSelectedDay(int day) 
{
    SelectedDay = day;
    UpdateCalendar(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
}

// Slightly change your UpdateCalendar method so that it uses the SelectedDay method
void UpdateCalendar(int year, int month)
{
    DateTime temp = new DateTime(year, month, SelectedDay);
    currDate = temp;
    MonthAndYear.text = temp.ToString("MMMM") + " " + temp.Year.ToString();
    int startDay = GetMonthStartDay(year, month);
    int endDay = GetTotalNumberOfDays(year, month);
    Date.text = currDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
}
```

**Explanation:**

The Unity UI system (not the newest one but the LTS one) uses Unity.EventSystems to handle user interaction.  This gives us access to a bunch of useful interfaces to easily handle things like clicking and dragging and mouse enter etc.  So we add a script to our desired UI object (the Days prefab) and we implement the [IPointerClickHandler interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html).  This requires us to add a `public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData evtData)` method.  That method will be fired whenever a user clicks on the attached UI object.

After that it's just a matter of doing what we want to do when the click happens.  In this case, we add a method to the Calendar script that updates a SelectedDay variable.  And we use that SelectedDay in the UpdateCalendar method.  Then we call the SetSelectedDay method whenever the a click occurs on a Day UI object.

**Additional Comments**

This code is a little messy and should be refactored for better separation of concerns.  Let me know how it goes because, as I said, I wrote it on the fly so it may have some errors.  I'll fix them in the answer if needed.

An alternative approach could be to use C# events and register handlers as necessary, but that's probably over engineering for this particular problem.  If your problem space becomes more complex, though, you can read up on [C# event handling and delegates here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event)

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer! I'm working on it now, and fingers crossed it'll work out just fine! I just have a question (maybe a silly one), but what is the new gameobject "dayText" that you added? what is it for or assigned to? (i'm pretty new to the whole coding thing and i'm trying to learn how these things work)

Comment: just got the updated comment - I really appreciate the extra explanation, it really helped! I'll be using this information again for other functionalities too, thank you! (Learning coding from scratch from Google or tutorials is a struggle because they dont start from basics, and use specific terminology that need another round of research on their own. and tutorials make it seem like it's the easiest thing on the planet, then youre left with errors upon errors in the code) Can't thank you enough for this!

Comment: The `dayText` object will be the Text child object of the Days prefab.  I assumed that's how your prefab was set up.  The idea was that, you set the number of the day using a public variable in the script and the script then sets that as the text value for the Text object in the prefab.  You can change that if your prefab is set up differently.

Comment: "Learning coding from scratch from Google or tutorials is a struggle because they dont start from basics, and use specific terminology that need another round of research on their own" - you just described my entire career in programming.  Don't worry, though, if you persevere you'll find yourself having "AHA!" moments more and more often.

Comment: I figured that's what you meant after posting the comment. The prefab is actually set up of 7 images and each have a Text child for the number of the day, and then this is duplicated to make the weeks. If I assign just one of these Texts to the script, would it still work to all of them? Also, I'm getting this error "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime". The issues are in the UpdateCalendar line in SetSelectedDay Method, and the first line of the UpdateCalendar method.

Comment: I really hope so. I find what you do and the ability to do it so fascinating and would love to get there too one day! Also, apologies if i'm taking too much of your time with this, and thank you!!

Comment: I updated the answer.  You will need to attach the DayScript to the *each* Image inside the Days prefab, instead.  The ArgumentOutOfRange exception is saying that one or all of the number values you are providing can't be made into a valid date.  Year and Month are fine but Day is invalid.  It could be that you're clicking on something like the 31st of February (which is an impossible date).  Also, make sure that you type a valid day number into the DayScript Day Number field in the Inspector.

Comment: it works now and displays it in the inputfield as well, YAY! But it only works for the month of June and if i've specified the days accordingly in the inspector - like you've mentioned, so when i go to choose a day from August, let's say, it doesnt work. Would I be able to remove the dayNumber completely from my script and have it read whatever day is updated onto the calendar instead? i.e it reads whatever day the UpdateCalendar puts into the text child.

Comment: To do that, you just need to modify the SetSelectedDay method so that it also takes a Year and Month parameter.  You can then pass those values into the UpdateCalender method call inside the SetSelectedDay method.  For this to work, each DayScript (i.e each Image with a DayScript attached) needs to know the Year and the Month that it belongs to.  This is something you will have to assign to it when the Calendar is generated and you can assign the dayNumber then, too.  But this falls outside the scope of the original question, I think.

Comment: If you found the answer that I provided to be useful, please mark it as the accepted answer.  That way it can help other users who may have a similar question to yours.